# I am getting this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: python

```
import re
import subprocess


def get_speaker_output_volume():
    
    cmd = "osascript -e 'get volume settings'"
    process = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = process.stdout.strip().decode('ascii')

    pattern = re.compile(r"output volume:(\d+), input volume:(\d+), "
                         r"alert volume:(\d+), output muted:(true|false)")
    volume, _, _, muted = pattern.match(output).groups()

    volume = int(volume)
    muted = (muted == 'true')
    print("Volume: ",volume)
    if muted==1:
        print("Volme is muted.")
    else:
        print("Volume is not muted.")
        
get_speaker_output_volume()
```

> volume, _, _, muted = pattern.match(output).groups()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: `pattern.match(output)` is returning `None` because it cannot find a match based on your regex pattern

Comment: How about you check what `output` is and see why your regular expression doesn't match it?